# timer not working in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer

i am using Python 2.7 for some coding for fun at home, and i can't figure out why this code doesn't work. I try it and it works fine, but says that i did in in -0.000938375024452 seconds...
any help very much appreciated

```
import timeit
import time
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
again = "yes"
print "Hi."
time.sleep(1)
print "How quick can you type the alphabet?"
time.sleep(1)
print "Well you're about to find out..."
while "YES" in again.upper():
    time.sleep(2)
    begin = raw_input("When you are ready, press enter and type the alphabet.")
    start = timeit.timeit()
    attempt1 = raw_input("")
    end = timeit.timeit()
    time1 = end - start
    if attempt1.upper() == alphabet.upper():
        print "Ok. You did it in..."
        time.sleep(1)
        print time1,"seconds!"
        time.sleep(1)
        again = raw_input("Would you like another go?")
    else:
        print "Sorry, but that was incorrect."
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Try again."
        again = "yes"
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `timeit.timeit()`? That will return a value which is the time taken to execute a `pass` statement.

Comment: Timer is working. It's just not doing what you expect. You can use `time.time()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`timeit.timeit()` does not return you a timestamp. It runs `pass` 1000000 times and returns you the duration of it.

[Docs for timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Use `time.time()` instead.

[time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time)